# White box in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitableview

I have a strange problem with my interface.
I have a `ViewController` with black background color and a have a `UIImageView` algo with a black background color.
On top of that a have a `TableView` with a light brown, my cell also have this color in the background.
But, when I test in the app, appears a white box on the right of the cell.
I dont know why this appears, someone can help?

[image: this a screenshot]

Comment: How do you add the arrow? Could the accessoryView set to white?

Comment: If possible, please post some code about how you set up the tableview cell.

Comment: @Larme I add the arrow with an image.


    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure.png"]];


But this image does not have a white background, because I use it in a Iphone Version for this app and i dont have this problem.

Comment: Get Spark Inspector (free trial), it will show the entire view layout in 3D and allow parameters to be changed in the running app. No changes have to be made to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is apparently the background of the arrow image. It is either in the image itself (which I doubt as you probably would've noticed that) or it's just the backgroundColor property of the view.

Do this after setting the accessoryView:

```
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: My arrow is a PNG without background.
But I put your code in my class thats manage the TableCell and works for me!
Thanks man